# pandas lambda function returns both df and series, why?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a `df` and a `lambda` function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'label' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
                  't' :      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, ],
                  'x' : [48,  6, 30, 30, 53, 48, 25, 51,  9, 55, 2]})
top3 = lambda x : x.groupby('t')['x'].idxmax().head(3)
```

I tried a few combinations of `label` and got varying results when the function is called:

```
print(df.groupby('label').apply(top3))

label  t
a      1     0
       2     1
       3     2
b      1     5
       2     6
       3     7
c      1     9
       2    10
Name: x, dtype: int64


df2 = df[df.label=='a']
print(df2.groupby('label').apply(top3))

t      1  2  3
label         
a      0  1  2


df3 = df[df.label.isin(['a', 'b'])]
print(df3.groupby('label').apply(top3))
t      1  2  3
label         
a      0  1  2
b      5  6  7
```

The first result is a Series while the next 2 are DataFrames. why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.groupby.apply()` has a lot of magic behind it to try to coerce things into what it thinks the best shape will be. When `c` is excluded from the passed dataframe, it can coerce things into a clean rectangular dataframe as a result, but with `c` included, it will fall back to a MultiIndex:

```
In [71]: df[df.label.isin(['a', 'c'])].groupby('label').apply(top3)
Out[71]:
label  t
a      1     0
       2     1
       3     2
c      1     9
       2    10
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

If you want to follow the rabbit hole in `pandas`' code, you can start here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/30362ed828bebdd58d4f1f74d70236d32547d52a/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py#L189